# How to apply condition onPreferenceClick in android?

Tags: java, android

This is my `myprefnces.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <PreferenceCategory>


  <ListPreference
     android:entries="@array/listOptions"
     android:entryValues="@array/listValues"
     android:key="listpref"
     android:summary="List preference example"
     android:title="List preference" />
 </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I have enter 3 value `array.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
   <string-array name="listOptions">
     <item>Facebook</item>
     <item>Gmail</item>
     <item>Twitter</item>
     </string-array>

   <string-array name="listValues">
     <item>1 </item>
     <item>2 </item>
     <item>3</item>
   </string-array>
 </resources>
```

`PreferencesActivityTest.class`

```
public class PreferencesActivityTest extends PreferenceActivity {
    public static final String PREF_BEER_SIZE = "listpref";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.my_prefrences);
        Preference beerPref = (Preference) findPreference(PREF_BEER_SIZE);
        beerPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                // how will apply function for each facebook twitter and gmail
                return false;

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want share my application link I have done sharing in another application I have code for this but I'm having problem with apply the condition how we'll apply function we select gmail or facebook or twitter mean on item select this prefnces I'm doing first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use OnPreferenceChangelistener rather than onPreferenceClickListener.

OnPreferenceClickListener is to do some task before click on the preference. In Preferenceclick you will have nothing to compare since it is a click on the view. Not the value being set

```
 beerPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
     public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference pref, Object newValue) {
         final ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) pref;
         final int idx = listPref.findIndexOfValue((String) newValue);

         //Depending upon idx execute
         return true;
     }
 });
```